# Convert time stored-into/sent-by C# long Variable into date time format under PHP

Tags: c#, php, api

I am getting "634999070963845181" which is stored C#'s long variable which is equivalent to "3/26/2013 3:04:56 PM". Now this "long" type time "634999070963845181" sent to my REST API (written in PHP). At Rest API side I want to get "3/26/2013 3:04:56 PM" from received "634999070963845181" in . But in date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', 634999070963845181) does not generate "3/26/2013 3:04:56 PM". The PHP time functions having return type "int".

Dear Ninja, how to get full time stamp in PHP from C# long variable holding time.

Comment: Hope this helps in your conversion http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/749/converting-datetime-ticks-to-a-unix-timestamp-and-back-in-php

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the C# side of the code, you should fix it to transmit timestamps in a standard format, such as ISO8601

Otherwise, you need to know two things about C# and PHP timestamps: their epoch (meaning of 0) and their units.

For PHP, this is seconds starting at 1st Jan 1970, while [C# uses the year 0001 and 100-nanosecond intervals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx).